# Angular UI Grid filter only applies to beginning of cell value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using an Angular UI Grid in my app. I set `enableFiltering` to `true` in the options which made some filter boxes show up above my columns. This is great, but the filters don't work exactly as desired.

If a cell contains the text "I like pizza" and I type "I like", that cell's row is shown as a match. I would also think that if I type "pizza", the "I like pizza" cell/row should show up, but that's not the case.

How can I get the filters to allow searching anywhere in the text, not just from the beginning?

Comment: The default is `STARTS_WITH`, but you can change it: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2839

Comment: @BradBarber that looks like the exact thing I want, although it's not clear how to actually use it. Any ideas?

Comment: In the columnDef where you want to use it, you'd add the following: `filter: {condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS}`

Comment: That did it. Thanks. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter: {condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS}` in the column definition to allow that column to search anywhere in the text.

Here's a sample column definition with this in place:

```
columnDefs: [
  // default
  { field: 'name',
    filter: {condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS} },
  ...
```

Comment: BTW, reader, don't forget to include `uiGridConstants` in your dependency injection.

Comment: Is there an advantage to this over writing a function?

Comment: @azium, I prefer to use any capabilities provided by a framework if it's available...they usually implement it better than I would. In this case they implemented the CONTAINS filter with a regex instead of indexOf which I think is a little faster (https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/js/core/services/rowSearcher.js#L149).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom filter object that takes a `condition` property, which can be a function that takes `searchTerm` and `cellValue`. Will display if the function returns `true`.
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nCfhyHnVZobR73WHdAp5?p=preview)

```
  { field: 'name', filter: {
    condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
      return cellValue.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1
    }
  }}
```

Comment: BTW, even though I didn't think this was the best way to accomplish what I was originally after, this code was helpful to me in a different way later, so thanks.